# Reset TFS work item templates to latest version?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to reset or start over with the latest version TFS work item template? I do not care about any existing work item history.

Scenario: I have a TFS project that has code, but never used work items. The existing template is too old to use the [automatic Configure Features wizard tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade). It is **ok** to mess up any work item history.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: What path did you take for this? Is there an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TFS-PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)

The built in **Work Item Templates** should override your existing ones. That might even work before updating, but i'd not recommend that try.

We had this trouble once too. A coworker fixed this after doing some kind of Troubleshooting guide. (Let me check tomorrow if i can find that one again)

Let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://nkdagility.com/tfs-process-template-migration-script-updated/
It covers off what you need to do, and includes some PowerShell to help you.